# ASP datapager PreRender with page redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, datapager

i have asp web page with listview in it. i added datapager to the listview with PreRender event to populte the listview with relevant data.in the PreRender event code i have redirect function as below in order to add current page number to the querystring.the problem is that this redirct generate the PreRender event and i have a loop with no exit.how can i add current page number to the querystring without having this loop?

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?keyword=" + keyword + "&Page=" + pagenumber, false);
```

Comment: Why are you doing redirect in PreRender stage? You have to create a link button with predefined parameters but not redirection.

Comment: i want to add cuurent page number to page querystring...